# ansible mysql query not showing results

Tags: ansible, mysql, ansible-galaxy

I have used community.mysql collection and was able to run a query against the database.

```
---
- name: Get stats of a file
  hosts: localhost
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: run mysql query
      community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_user: testuser
        login_password: testpass
        login_db: test_db
        query: SELECT * FROM STATION WHERE ID = %(id_val)s AND STATE = %(story_val)s
        named_args:
          id_val: 12
          story_val: AZ
      register: r_query
```

The playbook runs fine without errors

```
root@ip-172-31-83-231:/home/ubuntu# ansible-playbook sql_query.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Get stats of a file] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [run mysql query] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored
```

could not find the documentation on how to display the queries results.
Can you help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `community.mysql.mysql_query` module [documents its return values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_query_module.html#return-values) as:

- `executed_queries`
- `query_results`
- `rowcount`

So, if you're registering `r_query`, and you want to see the result, you can call `r_query.query_result`.

A common approach when developing playbooks initially is to send to `stdout` with a [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-debug-module) task:

```yaml
- name: Get stats of a file
  hosts: localhost
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: run mysql query
      community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_user: testuser
        login_password: testpass
        login_db: test_db
        query: SELECT * FROM STATION WHERE ID = %(id_val)s AND STATE = %(story_val)s
        named_args:
          id_val: 12
          story_val: AZ
      register: r_query

    - name: what happened
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ r_query.query_result }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This was not clear to me from the documentation nor could not find examples.